# C# + Unity string==string false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using TMP_Pro asset for input fields in my project.

```
input = inputText.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text.ToLower();
        commands = input.Split ('\n').OfType<string>().ToList();
//A few moments later
case "спрятан_фрукт()​": //(russian)
```

runtime: skip case "спрятан_фрукт()" and go to default

Also [That comes when I copy string from debugger (which it try to find) to script (which it checks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2w6f.png)
I think the problem comes from TMP_Pro but I don't know how to fix it.

Also: [trying to backspace it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUNd1.png) it goes to "== )"

Also: cp to Google those strings and it destroys ")"

Comment: is there any hidden whitespace - you could do a comparison character by character

Comment: What is whitespace? case "спрятан_фрукт()​" like this after CP. Also it works, when I CP from debugger. It also "hides" bracket and colors it into orange in MonoDevelop (and I can go there two times by arrows on keyboard)

Comment: can you show us the variable that you are doing the switch on in the debugger?

Comment: why is this marked as offtopic?

Comment: you know in Windows, `NewLine` is represented as CRLF `"\r\n"`, and when you split it by `'\n'`, you have still have the `'\r'` in there... Better split the string with `Envrionment.NewLine`

Comment: It is also a good practice to `Trim()` your strings after the split (assuming you don't want leading/trailing whitespace)

Comment: Normalizing the unicode strings before trying to compare them might work.  `String.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use StringReader class to properly split a text into lines

```
var text = inputText.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text.ToLower();
var reader = new System.IO.StringReader (text);
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    switch (line.Trim()) {
    case "спрятан_фрукт()​":
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you might wanna use the ToLower(CultureInfo) with Russian culture info or the ToLowerInvariant() method instead.